# Does anyone know this FIRMessaging error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have to reset up the firebase in the app that made 3 or 4 years ago by someone.
The problem is this one:

[image: first]

And this one:

[image: second]

What this problem is? I really don't know how to fix this one.
I just had tried to googling for solving this problem, but I couldn't find the exact answer.

Pods:

[image: third]

Can you please help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Podfile doesn't point to a specific version, probably it's outdated implementation, after you `pod install`, it fetch newest version, so the code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for direct channel was removed from Firebase last year in the [7.0.0 release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios). See the [FirebaseMessaging docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) for updating to APNS.